# Replace appsettings.json values when deploying docker to an app service via Github Actions

Tags: .net, docker, .net-core, dockerfile, github-actions

We are currently getting to grips with Docker deployments via Github Actions to deploy an application to an App Service.  Whilst the application is deployed in a container, we can't seem to figure out how we replace application settings via the github pipeline, or if that is even possible?

Our yaml file doesn't have any replacement setup, but we can't seem to find what the process is to handle this scenario.

```
name: appname-api-dev

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: self-hosted
   
    steps:
    - name: Log into registry
      uses: docker/login-action@v1
      #uses: docker/login-action@v2
      with:
          registry: ${{ secrets.ACR_NAME }}
          username: ${{ secrets.ACR_USERNAME }}
          password: ${{ secrets.ACR_PASSWORD }}
           
   
    - name: Docker Build & Push to ACR
      run: |
            cd src/App
            docker build -f Dockerfile .. --tag dummy.azurecr.io/repo/my-image-name:latest
            docker push dummy.azurecr.io/repo/my-image-name:latest
 
    - name: 'Login via Azure CLI'
      uses: azure/login@v1
      with:
        creds: ${{ secrets.AZURE_CREDENTIALS }}
 
    - uses: azure/webapps-deploy@v2
      with:
          app-name: 'appname-api-dev'
          publish-profile: ${{ secrets.AZURE_WEBAPP_PUBLISH_PROFILE }}
          images: dummy.azurecr.io/repo/my-image-name:latest
```

Comment: You have to do this at `dotnet publish` level. Since you have not included the `Dockerfile` I can guess you have build and publish steps (maybe with multistage build). You must create the `appsettings.whatever.json` with the settings you want and read it with the ENV variable, then if you want on the .csproj you can [conditionally skip the other appsettings.xxx.json](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/aspnet/web-forms/overview/deployment/advanced-enterprise-web-deployment/excluding-files-and-folders-from-deployment) maybe for security reason.